# Duplicate cookie issue between domain and subdomain

Tags: cookies

I have a scenario where I have to set cookie from subdomain to main domain to share cookie across subdomains.

```
// Function to set a cookie
export function setCookie(name, value) {
  const cookie = `${encodeURIComponent(name)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)};path=/;domain=.domain.com;`;
  document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

but the problem is I can see **duplicate cookie (CookieKey)** is being set based on the subdomain path.

[image]